# Register User with Firebase and AngularFire2

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable, angularfire2

In my app.component.ts, the am using this function to register the user onto firebase using angularFire2. However I am getting an error with "property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void".

```
register() {
    this.userService.registerUser(this.model)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                console.log('Registration successful')
            },
            error => {
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
```

and in my userService.ts, I have the following call getting data from firebase

```
registerUser(user: User) {
    this.angularFire.auth.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
    }).then(
    (success) => {
        console.log(success);
    }).catch(
    (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
}
```

I do understand why the error appears. Because my registerUse function in the userService does not return an observable. As I am new to typescript, how can I change that to become an observable such that I can console.log('Success') in the app.component.ts when the data comes back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward option would be to return the promise:

```ts
import { FirebaseAuthState } from 'angularfire2';

registerUser(user: User): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
  return this.angularFire.auth.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  })
  .then((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => {
    console.log(success);
    return authState;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  });
}
```

However, it you want to return an observable, you can use [`fromPromise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-fromPromise):

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import { FirebaseAuthState } from 'angularfire2';

registerUser(user: User): Observable<FirebaseAuthState> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.angularFire.auth.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  })
  .then((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => {
    console.log(success);
    return authState;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    throw error;
  }));
}
```

If you are going use a `catch` in `registerUser` to log the error, you should re-throw the error so that it can be caught and handled by the caller. If you don't need the logging, just leave it out and the caller can handle any errors (via the observable):

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import { FirebaseAuthState } from 'angularfire2';

registerUser(user: User): Observable<FirebaseAuthState> {
  return Observable.fromPromise(this.angularFire.auth.createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password
  }));
}
```

If you don't want to return AngularFire2's `FirebaseAuthState`, you can use a `then` to return something else as the promise's resolved value (which will be the value emitted by the observable).

Comment: Thanks cartant. I am getting an error at .then((user: firebase.User)

Argument of type (user: User) => user is not assignable to parameter of type '(a:FirebaseAuthState)=> any'.

Comment: It should be fixed. Switching back and forth between the Firebase SDK and AngularFire2 sometimes gets confusing.

Comment: Which one would you recommend to go for? SDK or AngularFire2? It seems to me that there the actual SDK has more documentation on it?

Comment: Both. AngularFire2 has nice list and object bindings, but doesn't cover the full API. However, there's no reason you cannot use both. AngularFire2's observables fit very nicely with Angular 2 - for lists, objects and auth.

Comment: I tried the Promise method and I had to change to firebase.Promise<FirebaseAuthState> and in the app.component, I change subscribe to then. Everything works fine after that. Thanks !

Comment: Yeah. I think which promise ends up getting used depends upon the order in which libraries and polyfill, etc. are included. Glad you have it working.